# Can I update a shared dropbox file while not changing the link?

Tags: dropbox, shared-folders

I have a file I would like to update on dropbox. About 900 people know this shared link.
However, when I update the file the link is changed, e.g. from

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9d8y345434554434693zs/Manual.pdf

to

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9d8y83gresgrrrzs/Manual.pdf

Is there a way to prevent this?

Sharing the folder is not enough, because I need direct links to at least one specific file.

Or are there alternatives? (not dropbox solutions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest thing for the future is to share the link to the folder instead of the file itself that way you can change the contents inside the folder without having to change links. Just have a folder per file.

Answer (score 10):

Upload with the same filename and override the old one.  I do this by simply dragging and dropping the new file (with the same exact filename as the old file) into dropbox.  The same link gets preserved and I can even look at previous versions of that same file by right clicking.

Comment: I don't use dropbox not for this feature anymore, however I gave a +1 for other readers.

Comment: it works very well

Comment: @LampShade - do you drop in the browser or in your local folder?

Comment: @DAE In the past I just used the web browser.  But you can sync Dropbox to your computer.  And if that's the case i would assume that does the same thing if the local folder is synced.  But I'd have to try it.

Comment: If a link breaks for anyone else, (i) restore the old version of the file prior to deletion/reupload, (ii) upload the new version **from the web browser** interface, and (iii) ensure sharing is set to the same mode as before, e.g. view.

Answer (score 4):

You can share a folder containing only that one file.

Comment: Also, try searching/proposing such a feature here: https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/

Comment: I have upvoted, but also edited the question.

Comment: Fair enough, as I didn't answer the question, just gave the half-way workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace the file with one named identically and in the same place, subsequent visitors will get the updated version.

source: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Sharing-and-collaboration/Can-I-replace-a-file-but-keep-the-same-link-The-link-has-already/td-p/61254

Comment: You could have just added this link to https://superuser.com/a/756086/13889 which says the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Open dropbox on your browser and drop there the new version of your file instead of dropping it to your local dropbox folder. Had same issue - Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it may help others.